# augmentation ideal for universal enveloping algebras

Tags: lie-algebras

Let $L$ be a restricted Lie algebra with the restricted enveloping algebra
$u(L)$ over a field $F$. Let $ω(L)$ denote the augmentation ideal of $u(L)$ which is the kernel of the augmentation map $\varepsilon : u(L) \mapsto F$ induced by $x\mapsto 0$. 
My question is  as follows:
Why the augmentation ideal is generated by $L$? 
May you please give an example?

Comment: Do you see that $L$ is contained in the kernel?

Comment: why is $L$ in kernel? Indeed , I want to know more about what augmentation map does?

Comment: You wrote yourself that this is the map induced by $x\mapsto 0$. I assume you know the precise formulation of this part?

Comment: yes, I wrote that according to the formal definition, the thing make me confused is that other elements of $u(L)$ which does not map to $0$?

Comment: No, the formal definition is not just $x\mapsto 0$, but includes a condition on what those $x$ can be.

Comment: May you please clarify it more?

Comment: You really need to look up the precise definition. Without that there is not much I can do to help.

Comment: I would be grateful if you could introduce a book including this notion.

Comment: But where did you see it?

Comment: I saw it in an article,  it was a very brief statement. http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1995-123-10/S0002-9939-1995-1264829-0/S0002-9939-1995-1264829-0.pdf

Comment: Sure, papers tend to assume the reader is familiar with the background material. Not sure what a good reference is for restricted Lie algebras though. Were there no references in the paper?

Comment: I looked for proper reference within this article, I could not find .

Comment: Which paper is it?

Comment: Restricted Lie algebras and their envelopes

Comment: The very last reference on the list is to a book which seems like it should be a good place to start.

Comment: I have already started reading some notations related to group rings, I suppose  I need to find out the way we correspond universal enveloping algebras to group ring?